# New Alpha users in Actions on Google and Action Releases

Tags: actions-on-google

When you add new users to the Alpha user white list in Actions on Google, do you need to release a new version of the Action for the new Alpha users to access the Action?

Answer (score 0):

No, anyone on the alpha approved list will be able to use the alpha version of an action (although it may take a few hours).

However, keep in mind that this doesn't happen automatically. They need to opt into the alpha version by going to the directory listing of the Action on an Android phone using a real browser and indicating they want to use the alpha verison.